# GLPK optimization problem with continuous variables always return zero

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, glpk

In an optimization problem with continuous variables, I used GLPK for python (pymprog module). The result is not what I'd expect.

```
begin('optimzer')

X = var('X', 5)
k = par('k', [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

0 <= X[0] <= 100
100 <= X[1] <= 200
400 <= X[2] <= 500
400 <= X[3] <= 500
400 <= X[4] <= 500

sum(k[i]*X[i] for i in range(len(k))) >= 150
minimize(sum(k[i]*X[i] for i in range(len((k)))), 'Profit')

solve()
save(mip='_save.mip')
```

The result is this

```
Problem:    optimzer
Rows:       1
Columns:    5 (0 integer, 0 binary)
Non-zeros:  5
Status:     INTEGER UNDEFINED
Objective:  Profit = 0 (MINimum)

   No.   Row name        Activity     Lower bound   Upper bound
------ ------------    ------------- ------------- -------------
     1 R1                          0           150               

   No. Column name       Activity     Lower bound   Upper bound
------ ------------    ------------- ------------- -------------
     1 X[0]                        0             0           100 
     2 X[1]                        0           100           200 
     3 X[2]                        0           400           500 
     4 X[3]                        0           400           500 
     5 X[4]                        0           400           500 

Integer feasibility conditions:

KKT.PE: max.abs.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        max.rel.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        High quality

KKT.PB: max.abs.err = 4.00e+02 on column 3
        max.rel.err = 9.98e-01 on column 3
        SOLUTION IS INFEASIBLE

End of output
```

Why is the status INTEGER UNDEFINED, if I'm working with continuous variables?

How can profit be 0 with the given constraint that it shoud be >= 150?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a MIP model but a pure LP model (glpk seems to make a distinction). You can save the LP solution by:

```
save(sol='_save.sol')
```

That will show:

```
Problem:    optimzer
Rows:       1
Columns:    5
Non-zeros:  5
Status:     OPTIMAL
Objective:  Profit = 1300 (MINimum)

   No.   Row name   St   Activity     Lower bound   Upper bound    Marginal
------ ------------ -- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
     1 R1           B           1300           150

   No. Column name  St   Activity     Lower bound   Upper bound    Marginal
------ ------------ -- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
     1 X[0]         NL             0             0           100             1
     2 X[1]         NL           100           100           200             1
     3 X[2]         NL           400           400           500             1
     4 X[3]         NL           400           400           500             1
     5 X[4]         NL           400           400           500             1

Karush-Kuhn-Tucker optimality conditions:

KKT.PE: max.abs.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        max.rel.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        High quality

KKT.PB: max.abs.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        max.rel.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        High quality

KKT.DE: max.abs.err = 0.00e+00 on column 0
        max.rel.err = 0.00e+00 on column 0
        High quality

KKT.DB: max.abs.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        max.rel.err = 0.00e+00 on row 0
        High quality

End of output
```

It seems that `save(mip='_save.mip')` only works when there is at least one discrete variable in the model.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the MIP. I thought that the M(ixed) stood for Mixed Integer and Float. But I don't understand the answer of GLPK: shouldn't the answer be X[1] = 150 and all other X[n] = 0, with a resulting R1 = 150? I asked to minimize the profit

Comment: Obviously your proposed solution violates the lower bounds so it is not feasible.

Comment: Sorry, I did previous tests with different bounds and my mind was still set to them